# React Redux handle multiple data (from one type) on one page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have to create a page where I have to load 2 tables that are showing the products from an api. They have different properties (like filters, page, size on page, etc). How I can do this when I have only one reducer that handles the products stuff? Should I create 2 reducers? (I don't think that's the best way)

Comment: you can always destrucure the columns that you need from the props available through store

Comment: If I understand you I you that I can create a product store that will be object and as a key it will save the unique properties of the request (filters, page, size of the page)?

Comment: That reducer can save the unique properties and in the container you can destructure the required ones

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use two separate containers with mapStateToProps different for each.  You certainly don't want to duplicate any state, so you're right to assume that two separate reducers is not the way to go from what you're describing.

Comment: Something like a selector?